# Make executable a PyQt5 project

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I've tried to make a PyQt5 project an executable file.

I used a PyInstaller module, and I got a half success.

```
pyinstaller --clean -w -F --specpath=spec -n=project_name -i="..\resource\logo.ico" src\main.py
```

The executable file generated by this command did not run successfully.

The error message was like this.

[image]

```
pyinstaller --clean -c -F --specpath=spec -n=project_name -i="..\resource\logo.ico" src\main.py
```

The executable file generated by this command ran successfully.

But it has a terminal even though it is a GUI project.

The difference is just `-c` and `-w`. But one can be executed and can not one.

How should I do it?

Comment: I try to debug. So I ran `pyinstaller --clean -c -F -D --specpath=spec -n=project_name -i="..\resource\logo.ico" src\main.py`. However it works well.

Comment: Thanks, @eyllanesc. I'll try that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was subprocess.Popen with Python v3.7.5.

I didn't set the stdin. I set only stdout, stderr.

After I set the `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

And I want to add 1 more thing.

I've imported the win32api module with Python v3.8.0. This raises issues.

So, I've added the module `pywintypes`, and now the issue is resolved.

**Before**

```py
import win32api
```

**After**

```py
import pywintypes
import win32api
```